# Ambiguous error when deploying Next js project to Vercel: "Failed to compile."

Tags: reactjs, next.js, deployment, vercel

When deploying my Next js project to Vercel, I got a bunch of errors. I debugged most of them but the project still wouldn't build successfully.
[image]

I'm not sure where to look to resolve this issue. Does anyone know if I have to reconfigure a file for deployment or something? The only other suspicion I have is that Vercel is trying to execute things with yarn, but it's not one of the project dependencies.

I tried reconfiguring eslint and React to get rid of some of the errors. But there are still "4 errors" accordingly to Vercel and all of them are very ambiguous.